# SQLite LIKE

Tags: sqlite3, android, java, sql

То что ниже код приведен все работает. Тут это моя вина, вчера не учел что мне нужно передавать слова для поиска в верхнем регистре. :D
Но спасибо, что подправили, ибо реально запрос был "разбит",как подсказал уважаемый **Yura Ivanov**.

//******************************************************

Здравствуйте.
Вот пишу приложение `android`, где идет поиск в тексте в ячейке по слову.
Пытаюсь сформировать запрос. Использую `rawQuery`. 
Для поиска по слову используется `LIKE` (можно и `CONTAINS`). 
Синтаксис `Contains`, если что: `CONTAINS (column_name,'@search_word');`
*Подправил.*

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+_column1+" LIKE ?");
String[] _for_query={" '%"+_name+"%'"};
cursor = database.rawQuery(query.toString(),_for_query);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_column1));
        String str2 =" "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_column2));
        ...
        //В textView все
        }

    cursor.close();
```

Но запрос не выполняете. 
Подскажите как правильно?

P.s. извините если где глупость спорол, писал сонными глазами :)
Давайте так, если кто то что то недопонял:
как составить запрос с `CONTAINS/LIKE`

Поставил в цикл с `moveToNext` логи чтобы выводил:

```
   Log.i("str ==", str);
    Log.i("str2 == ", str2);
```

Отладчик не выводит ничего. По идеи он в цикл вообще не заходит.

//******************************************************

Comment: @Sheldon ты уверен, что есть такая функция `CONTAINS()`? я че то не могу найти такую в документации...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx
на msdn описана

Comment: @Sheldon Э, паря - это же Transact SQL - диалект SQL для MS SQL Server'а! И для SQLite это не применимо!!!

Comment: да, я уже разобрался с этим.Вчера просто Like не работал и я кинулся во все тяжкие.
и перешел на Contains.
Но сегодня разобрался окончательно Like работает, уж точно:)
Спасибо за отклик)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1 like ? or column2 like ?
```

и параметры:

```
String[] _for_query = {_name, _name};
```

Часть запроса не может быть параметром. движок субд должен суметь приготовить запрос к выполнению (prepare), а у вас получается кусок от запроса только есть. Аналогично, например, нельзя параметризовать таблицу из которой идет выборка. Параметризовать можно только значения с которыми идет сравнение.

Comment: да. я уже это понял утром)На сонную голову писал.
Исправленный вариант разместил в шапке.

Comment: но сама проблема с циклом. он не выполняется. 
Даже ошибок нет в отладчике.